# Regular Expression To get the string of a Youtube Video

Tags: objective-c, regex, ipad, youtube

I want to download a youtube video from a link say:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s

How to get the mp4 version of this flash video using regular expression, with Objective-c?
Please point me to some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do it with any Regular expression since youtube videos are in FLV format and are being played via a custom flash player when watched over a browser.
while using the iPhone / Ipad the iOS has a alternative player which is build into the OS and plays the video for you. that is why you can play youtube videos using this technique.

I would suggest opening youtube videos as it is intended in the SDK documentations
check out this link: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

Comment: I want to download that video programmatically.

Comment: not completely correct what "hewy" said. of course you cannot use regExp to get the download link but Youtube videos are also in mp4 format which can be played in iOS with no problem. I'm a Flash developer and has recently published my little YouTube Parser lib which you can get an idea from it: https://github.com/myflashlab/AS3-youtube-parser-video-link